# Онлайн редактирование html сайта

Tags: javascript, html

Товарищи, подскажите есть ли готовые решения или какие либо примеры для онлайн редактирование html сайта?

То есть, есть одна html страничка, нужно на ней на лету поменять цвета определенных div и ссылок, а затем отправить это все методом пост дальше.

Буду очень признателен любым советам и подсказкам.

**UPD**

Я хочу редактировать свою страницу. чтобы можно было по играться с цветами блоков, с цветами ссылок в определенных местах, а при достижении определенного результата отправить значение цветов на следующую страницу методом пост.

По примеру как это в wordpress, только больше функционала (выбора разных цветов для разных блоков и т.д.) http://ssmaker.ru/22f986c0.jpg

Comment: Вы хотите редактировать чужие html страницы?

Comment: Уточните, что Вы имеете ввиде под "оправить методом пост дальше". Что именно отправляется и куда?

Comment: Обновил ответ .

Comment: https://notbadwebeditor.github.io/defaultwebpage/ Вот... попробуй, HTML, JS, CSS

Answer (score 2):

да есть такое - но только изменения будут видны только у вас - так как на самом сайте ( т.е сам html вы не измените ) - [MagiCss](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/magicss?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)
это оно - написано расширение для Chrome - [image: вот скрин его работы]

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте в адресную строку на нужном сайте данную строчку и нажмите enter.

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0
```

(Будьте внимательны при копировании строки, браузер может вырезать "javascript:" из неё.)

Затем попробуйте кликнуть по любому элементу страницы ;)
Но, опять же, изменения будут видны только вам и нет возможности редактирования CSS.

Так же современные браузеры имеют встроенные инструменты для разработчиков.
Например: [Firefox DeveloperTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) и [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Answer (score 0):

Смотри в сторону CMS.

Из платных знаю wix и motocms3.

Там есть дизайнер - прям на лету и правишь сайт.

Так же есть модули к вордпресу, но вроде тоже платные.